# Prolog: How to get oldest and youngest in bloodline

Tags: prolog

Let's say that I have a bloodline of male population Williams and Skywalker families as my knowledge base:

```
father(phil,tom, williams).
father(tom, bob, williams).
father(bob, robert, williams).
father(robert, steve, williams).

father(anakin, luke, skywalker)
father(luke, finn, skywalker)
father(finn, andrew, skywalker)
father( andrew, charles, skywalker)
```

Which rule can I use to know the oldest and youngest in bloodline?

For example

```
?- oldestYoungest(skywalker,X,Y)
```

should return

```
X = anakin
Y = charles
```

Comment: What have you tried? I feel compelled to point out that Prolog variables start with upper-case letters, so your knowledge base is basically the same as `father(X, Y, Z)` over and over again; you should lowercase the names or nothing interesting will happen.

Comment: Sorry I have fixed the upper-case letters.

Comment: putting names inside quotes also works: `father('Anakin', 'Luke', 'Skywalker').` .

Comment: Rule that I have tried was oldestYoungest(FamilyName,X,Y):- father(X,_Y,FamilyName), father(_X,Y,FamilyName).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works with your Knowledge Base (KB) looking the way it does now.

```
youngest(LastName, Son) :-
    father(_, Son, LastName),
    \+father(Son, _, LastName).

oldest(LastName, Father) :-
    father(Father, _, LastName),
    \+father(_, Father, LastName).

oldestYoungest(LastName, Oldest, Youngest) :-
    youngest(LastName, Youngest),
    oldest(LastName, Oldest).
```

You should note that Prolog variables are upper-case and constants (or facts) are lower-case.

Technically, this answer finds oldest as the person with no father in the KB and the youngest and the person with no son in the KB. It works because your KB is defined that way.

Comment: You can mark the answer correct if it solved your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your help!